Is this narration about punishment of zina authentic?

Al-Zawahir ‘an Iqtiraaf Al-Kaba’ir (2/225)
It was also reported: “Whoever commits adultery with a married woman will have half of the punishment of this nation in the grave for her and for him. When the Day of Resurrection comes, God Almighty will judge her husband regarding his good deeds. This is if it was without his knowledge. If he knew and kept quiet, God will forbid him Paradise, because God Almighty wrote on its door: ‘You are forbidden to the cuckold.’”

Edit: The Arabic text -
التخريج من المصادر العربية
الزواجر عن اقتراف الكبائر: (٢/ ٢٢٥)
وورد أيضا: «إن من زنى بامرأة متزوجة كان عليه وعليها في القبر نصف عذاب هذه الأمة، فإذا كان يوم القيامة يحكم الله تعالى زوجها في حسناته، هذا إذا كان بغير علمه، فإن علم وسكت حرم الله عليه الجنة؛ لأن الله تعالى كتب على بابها أنت حرام على الديوث
Is this true and authentic?
If anyone has knowledge please comment or answer.

The narration you quoted may be found in works like Al-Zawajir, but it does not appear in the authentic collections of hadith, and it cannot be considered definitive or fully reliable in terms of its attribution. It’s important to treat such narrations with caution unless verified by more reliable sources, such as those found in Sahih Bukhari, Sahih Muslim, or other well-verified collections.
Allah knows best.

Thanks for reply. Has anyone verified it any single Islamic Book where the author has studies it's chain?
